# Is there a more concise way to get single column results from (Rust) SQLx?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

Currently I have:

```
/// The format which SQLx will use to return our rows.
#[derive(sqlx::FromRow, Debug)]
struct FooRow {
    foo: String,
}

pub async fn page(
    Extension(pool): Extension<PgPool>,
    ...
) -> PageTemplate {
    // find the available callsigns
    let rows = sqlx::query_as::<_, FooRow>(r#"SELECT foo FROM bar GROUP BY foo"#)
    .fetch_all(&pool)
    .await
    .unwrap();

    let foos: Vec<String> = rows.into_iter().map(|foo_row| foo_row.callsign).collect();
```

`String` does not implement `FromRow` and so I always need a wrapper struct.

Is there a more concise way of getting a column of `String`s from SQLx, without needing a wrapper struct and iteration mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`query_scalar`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/fn.query_scalar.html), which is the function for this exact purpose:

```
let rows: Vec<String> = sqlx::query_scalar::<_, String>(r#"SELECT foo FROM bar GROUP BY foo"#)
    .fetch_all(&pool)
    .await?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Tuple types up to 9 components also implement [`FromRow`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.FromRow.html), so if your query returns a single column, a [single-item tuple](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.FromRow.html#impl-FromRow%3C%27r,+R%3E-for-(T1,)) is enough.

```
let rows = sqlx::query_as::<_, (String,)>(r#"SELECT foo FROM bar GROUP BY foo"#)
    .fetch_all(&pool)
    .await?;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used this to simplify my code.  `rows` is now of type `Vec<(String,)>` (not the preferred `Vec<String>`) so it still needs mapping with a simple destructuring, but this does save the creation of a pointless `FooRow`.